# How can I make a type predicate that only narrows if it returns true?

Tags: typescript

For example, an `isLongString` function that returns `true` if and only if the argument is a `string` with more than `10` characters couldn't be (naively) implemented as a type predicate because it might confuse the compiler into narrowing incorrectly.

```js
function isLongString(v: unknown): v is string {
  return typeof v === "string" && v.length > 10;
}

const shortString = "short" as string | number;

if (isLongString(shortString)) {
  const tst: string = shortString;

  // @ts-expect-error
  const tst2: number = shortString;
} else {
  // @ts-expect-error
  const tst: string = shortString;

  // @ts-expect-error
  const tst2: number = shortString;
}
```

([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgGQQcwMpQE4xiYAUAbgFyLgDWYcA7mAJSWnIqIr6GaIDeAWABQiRHgCmUEHiRQAngAdxcYIjYBeTYgBEXAkW2IAZEbUA6ADbiiUABaIAfIgCMABgDcwgL7DhEBFyctnB4ULj6vOo6KMGhhgCGHHo8iAA+iGAgALYARuJ4nkLCMKrEqBhE4TzEMSFh3ERMTPzCov5ggVBclMlEiFG1oVVEha2IAPTjiAACXQC04gAeStALeHghY+2dXABMlJm5+f1BdcOYhV6I4hYo4i0iE1OzKAvL4qv5G3hbAVCIXSgPQakVOQxBo0ekxm8yWKyga2+vw6-0B+wy2TyeBOg3qEUuQA))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A close approximation to this would be to use a unique type.

```js
function isLongString(v: unknown): v is string & {__limitedPredicate: "isLongString"} {
  return typeof v === "string" && v.length > 10;
}
```

([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgGQQcwMpQE4xiYAUAbgFyLgDWYcA7mAJSWnIqIr6GaIBkiAN4B9YQBsYAWxhQApgBMACngUwIAQzmUARKgxFcBItoC+QgLAAoRIhVQQeJFACeAB1lxgiNgF4-ibS4jTG1+AVIAOjFZIigAC0QAPkQARgAGAG4rEysrCAQuTji4PChDHkQfAJRi0tD1DiCKgB9EMBBJACNZPCzLKxgvYj0scqJiGpKy7iImJgtrRHywQqguSiaiSqKpscw+qxsAeiPEAAE1gFpZAA93aGu8PBLDpYKoRDWoACZKdq6ettJqU9n0zLIxChZAtjqcLihrndZA8es88K9lqt1pwZrwqsDpsEDosTucrrd7lBHmiMe9Plxfm0Ot08EDaoSeGCgA))

If the predicate returns `true`, the unique type can be used nearly identically to a `string`. If the predicate returns `false`, TypeScript can't narrow the type at all because all it knows is `v` is not the unique type.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript's type system isn't able to express types like "a string of length at least 11", although if you wanted "a string of length *exactly* 11" then you could write that like `string & {length: 11}`. If you have a type like this, which is an intersection of two types, then narrowing will (typically) be one-way in the sense that no narrowing is done in the `else` branch, because it isn't known which of the two intersected types was not satisfied. (Narrowing would still occur in a union like `(string & {length: 11}) | number`, of course.)

In the specific case of strings, you may be able to solve your problem by writing a suitable [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) which your type guard checks for. For example:

```
function isStringStartingWithFoo(s: unknown): s is `foo${string}` {
    return typeof s === 'string' && s.startsWith('foo');
}
```

Unfortunately there is no (sane) way to use a template literal type to describe "a string of length at least 11", but if your function is testing something more concrete than that, then a template literal type may be the way forward.

---

In the general case, the solution is to write a return type like `v is string & ...` with an intersection type. The `...` part could be something fictitious, as in @johncs's answer. Using fictitious properties to emulate [nominal types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) is quite standard in Typescript, and shouldn't lead to incorrect code because nobody will have any reason to try to access the non-existent property. However, you could still instead write something true which is related to the fact that the string has a length of at least 11.

For example, you could say that the type guard checks that it's a string whose `match` method doesn't return `null` when called with the regex `.{11,}`:

```
type LongString = string & {match(regex: '.{11,}'): RegExpMatchArray}

function isLongString(v: unknown): v is LongString {
  // ...
}
```

(Note that this doesn't prevent calling `match` with other arguments, because intersection types of functions or methods are like overloads.) This is a bit clumsy in this example because you are unlikely to ever want to call `.match('.{11,}')` exactly on a string anyway, but one can imagine examples where it is actually useful, perhaps a type guard that checks `v is MyDataStructure & {isEmpty(): false}` or something similar.